# Matlab xlsread while Excel File is Open

Tags: excel, matlab, file-io

I need to use the xlsread command (and eventually the xlswrite command) in Matlab to import/export data from/to Excel.  However, I need to do this **while the excel file is open**.  Is this possible? How to do it?

Thanks,

Alaa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xlsread` is does not care if the file is already open or not.  Just use it with the standard calling convention.

```
[numData, txtData, rawData] = xlsread('filename.xls')
```

To use `xlswrite` on an open file, you need to open the file in a way that allows changes.  There are two ways to do this, by opening it read-only, or using the "share" feature.

**To use the "share" feature**

1. First, set up your spreadsheet to allow writes from multiple simultaneous users.  In Office 2007 you do this from the "review" ribbon, "share workbook", "allow changes by more than one user at the same time ..."
2. After performing an `xlswrite` from Matlab, you need to press save in the open file to force the changes to appear.

**To open the file read-only**

From Excel, press the open icon, select the file, and use the "Open read only" drop down selection in the "Open" dialog box.  In this case it looks like you have to re-open the file to get the new data to appear.

Comment: Thank you very much Pursuit!  Both options work.  This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer from @Pursuit. You could also try looking at the command `actxGetRunningServer`.